# Synchronous Counter using JK flip-flop not behaves as expected

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to do an exercise in the book "Verilog HDL" by Sanir Panikkar: design a synchronous counter using JK flip-flop.

JK flip-flop circuit provided in the book:
[image: JK flipflop circuit]

Counter circuit:
[image]

I believe there's a mistake in the above circuit: Input to the 3 AND gate should be Q0, Q1, Q2 from left to right, respectively; not Q1, Q2, Q3. With that modification, I wrote this code:

```
module verilogtest(clk, CS, q, clr);
    input clk, CS, clr;
    output[3:0] q;
    
    counter count(clk, CS, q, clr);
    
endmodule

module counter(clk, CS, q, clr);
    input clk, CS, clr;
    output[3:0] q;
    
    wire t1, t2, t3;
    
    assign #1
        t1 = CS & q[0],
        t2 = t1 & q[1],
        t3 = t2 & q[2];
    
    mJKff ff1(q[0], CS, CS, clk, clr);
    mJKff ff2(q[1], t1, t1, clk, clr);
    mJKff ff3(q[2], t2, t2, clk, clr);
    mJKff ff4(q[3], t3, t3, clk, clr);
    
endmodule

module mJKff(Q, J, K, clk, clr);
    output Q;
    input J, K, clk, clr;
    
    wire
        a, b, c, d, y, ybar, cbar, qbar;
    
    assign #1
        a    = ~(qbar & J & clk & clr),
        b    = ~(clk & K & Q),
        y    = ~(a & ybar),
        ybar = ~(y & clr & b),
        c    = ~(y & cbar),
        d    = ~(ybar & cbar),
        cbar = ~clk;
        
    assign #1
        qbar = ~(Q & clr & d),
        Q    = ~(c & qbar);
        
endmodule
```

I compile successfully with Quartus II and get a bunch of warnings:

> Warning: Timing Analysis is analyzing one or more combinational loops as latches
>
> Warning: The Reserve All Unused Pins setting has not been specified, and will default to 'As output driving ground'.
>
> Warning: Found pins functioning as undefined clocks and/or memory enables
>
> Warning: Found 7 node(s) in clock paths which may be acting as ripple and/or gated clocks -- node(s) analyzed as buffer(s) resulting in clock skew
>
> Warning: Circuit may not operate. Detected 2 non-operational path(s) clocked by clock "clk" with clock skew larger than data delay. See Compilation Report for details.
>
> Warning: Circuit may not operate. Detected 1 non-operational path(s) clocked by clock "CS" with clock skew larger than data delay. See Compilation Report for details.
>
> Warning: Circuit may not operate. Detected 1 non-operational path(s) clocked by clock "clr" with clock skew larger than data delay. See Compilation Report for details.

I think the last 3 warning is the reasons why it doesn't work.
Simulation result:
[image]

Zoom in:
[image]

Q0 behaves as expected, but the rest is not. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You just have a simple error in wiring the AND gates in your counter module:

```
assign #1
    t1 = CS & q[0],
    t2 = t1 & q[1],
    t3 = t2 & q[2];
```

should be

```
assign #1
    t1 = CS & q[1],
    t2 = t1 & q[2],
    t3 = t2 & q[3];
```

`Q[0]` is the only output behaving correctly because the JK inputs of all the other FFs are receiving the wrong values.